# How to get the site link in salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites, formula-field, site.com

I'm planning to get the site link and use it in the Formula Custom Field.

I have this code:

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/eventregistration?id="+ Id ,"/apex/eventregistration?id="+ Id)
```

But it links only the base url not the site url.

This is my sample site url:

```
http://samplesite.ap2.force.com/
```

What I want is create a formula custom field that will produce like this:

```
HYPERLINK("http://samplesite.ap2.force.com/apex/eventregistration?id="+ Id ,"http://samplesite.ap2.force.com/apex/eventregistration?id="+ Id)
```

**The problem is we can't create static link** `"http://samplesite.ap2.force.com/apex/eventregistration?id="+ Id` since we need to install the package to other organisation with a unique site url.Like example 
organisation site `"http://othersite.ap2.force.com/"`.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Ratan let me try this one..

Comment: @Ratan it has an error sir.. https://%24site.domainurlfor%28%24page.pagename%29/apex/eventregistration?id=a002800000NJogs

Comment: try `{!$Site.BaseUrl}/{!URLFOR($Page.PageName)}`